# Is it possible to use libraries written in an old version of swift in a project with a newer version of swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a project in Swift 3. However, many libraries are still using Swift 2.3.

Is there a way of making use of them in my project as they are?

Since it's possible to use Objective C libraries in Swift, I figure there's a chance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this reference from Apple answers the question:

unfortunately it would seem to be impossible:

> First, Swift 2.3 and Swift 3 are not binary compatible so your app's entire code base needs to pick one version of Swift.

https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=36

Comment: LOL thanks Rohan.  Actually it's one of those cases where I had utterly no idea about this, and just researched the answer myself!  :O